# How to send bunch emails from Amazon SES

Tags: php, email, amazon-ses

I have a subscriber base of 8000 and I want to send them emails at the same time using code based PHP (through API). But Amazon SES does not allow me to send more than 70 emails per second. How to send 8000 emails in one go, at the same time?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write to AWS for increase in limit. For that you can [click here](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/extendedaccessrequest/)

Also make sure that you are not operating in sandbox mode. [More details here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)